# Programming Library for Matrices over GF

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am looking for a Library in Java or C for doing matrix operations (mainly RANK) over certain Finite Field (GF).

I used Jama, but it has no Finite Field Functionality.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Unlikely you'll find your answer here. Maybe try scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

**C**

The best thing I would recommend to you is to use [NTL library](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/).

You will be probably interested in classes:

- mat_GF2:   matrices over GF(2); includes basic matrix arithmetic operations, including determinant calculation, matrix inversion, solving nonsingular systems of linear equations, and Gaussian elimination
- mat_GF2E:  matrices over GF2E; includes basic matrix arithmetic operations, including determinant calculation, matrix inversion, solving nonsingular systems of linear equations, and Gaussian elimination

It also supports rank operation you mentioned.

For more modules/classes please refer to the [documentation](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-modules.html).

**JAVA**

currently I am using [BouncyCastle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) that has some basic support for GF2, GF2^n matrices. Personally I am using source code of BouncyCastle library extending it on my own for desired features. A few useful methods are private/protected.

Please refer to [JavaDoc](http://www.borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/prov/org/bouncycastle/pqc/math/linearalgebra/package-summary.html) for more information.